# How to create a tvOS icon without Photoshop

Tags: icons, tvos

Reading the Apple documentation it seems mandatary to use Photoshop CC 2014 or 2015 to create the parallax for icons and images for tvOS store. Is possible use another tool or we are forced to use Photoshop?

Comment: The parallax icon is just three different PNG format images. Any photo editor that can save in PNG format could be used. *it seems mandatary to use Photoshop CC 2014 or 2015*, could you provide a link to where this is stated please.

Comment: Hi Daniel, it's not stated in no place, just my opinion reading the documentation of ParallaxExporter tool where is write that for use the plugin is required PS 2014 or 2015. Now I know that it's as you posted: to create the Icon you have just to create 3 images and import them in Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to deal with .lsr file at all. You just need to have separate PNG file for each layer, and construct the "App Icon - Small" with them in the asset file. Xcode even gives you a nice Parallax preview.

Therefore, you don't need to use PhotoShop at all. Any app that can deal with PNG files (even the Preview app of OSX) is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the same [page on the Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/download/) where you see Parallax Exporter, you'll also see a download for Parallax Previewer. The description for that reads,

> If you don’t use Adobe Photoshop, you can also use Parallax Previewer to assemble the individual layers and export a layered image.

Parallax Exporter is just a convenience for people using Photoshop, not the only way to get layered icons made.

Answer (score 2):

You're forced to use photoshop for now. Of course, this lsr metadata isn't all that difficult.

You could try generate the .lsr yourself, (mind you this is extremely painful)

In the root directory create a json file:

```
//Contents.json
{
      "layers": [
        {
          "filename": "top-layer.imagestacklayer"
        },
        {
          "filename": "highlight-layer.imagestacklayer"
        },
        {
          "filename": "shadow-layer.imagestacklayer"
        },
        {
          "filename": "middle-layer.imagestacklayer"
        },
        {
          "filename": "back-layer.imagestacklayer"
        }
      ],
      "info": {
        "version": 1,
        "author": "photoshop lsr plugin 1.1"
      },
      "properties": {
        "canvasSize": {
          "width": 400,
          "height": 240
        }
      }
    }
```

Each of the "filename" values, create a directory for each of them.
In each of the directories create another JSON file:

```
//Contents.json
    {
      "info": {
        "version": 1,
        "author": "photoshop lsr plugin 1.1"
      },
      "properties": {
        "frame-size": {
          "width": 400,
          "height": 240
        },
        "frame-center": {
          "x": 200,
          "y": 120
        }
      }
    }
```

Also nest a new directory in it called Content.imageset

Inside this new directory implement another json file:

```
//Contents.json
{
  "info": {
    "version": 1,
    "author": "photoshop lsr plugin 1.1"
  },
  "images": [
    {
      "idiom": "universal",
      "filename": "back-layer.png",
      "scale": "1x"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also include in this directory the .png

So it should look something like this:
[image]

Last but not least, compress using .zip and change the file extension to .lsr

Comment: I David, thank you for your post, very technical, beyond my knowledge. I think I asked the question in the wrong way.

Comment: Any idea how to convert that .lsr file to a .lcr file without using photoshop or the (macOS only) command line tool? E.g. programmatically on a unix command line?